# How to rewrite my ($one, $two) = @ARGV and execute it when program is running?

Tags: perl

Is it possible? I'd like to rewrite construction:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

my ($one, $two) = @ARGV
```

User input two arguments. E.g. `one`, `two`. 
Program is running. 
How to execute program with new $one, $two, (args) when program is work?

Comment: Yes you can run your program like `perl program.pl one two`. Then the arguments `one` and `two` will end up in `@ARGV`

Comment: @Håkon Hægland, yeah, i know it! How to rewrite $one, $two, and execute program again, when program is works?

Comment: You want to change the arguments of an already running program? You need some other mechanism to get those changes, like a UNIX socket.

Comment: @tadman, yes, i want to change args of an already running program! So, is it possible?

Comment: @d1553ct10n Please explain a little bit more of how your program works. How is it supposed to receive the changed arguments while it is running?

Comment: Also, what should happen to the work it has already done with the initial arguments? What if it's just in a middle of processing the file "one" and replacing the file "two"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable `@ARGV` is a normal array that just happens to be populated with arguments from the command line. It's not read-only nor do those strings mean anything special. It's up to you to use them however you will.

This means that you can start your program, inspect the elements of `@ARGV`, and change them however you like. All of the array operations, such as `shift`, `push`, `splice`, and so on work.

If you'd like another copy of the same program, you can run `system` with `$^X` (the current path to Perl) with the new arguments that you choose:

```
 system $^X, @new_args;
```

Or, to restart the process you are currently in, you can use `exec`:

```
 exec $^X, @new_args;
```

Beyond that your problem is too light on details and motivation to suggest anything more meaningful.